# Can't verify if a shape is a triangle

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from math import sqrt
a = raw_input("First length: ")
b = raw_input("Second length: ")
c = raw_input("Third length: ")
if a >0 and b >0 and c >0 and a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a :
    if a == b == c:
        print "Equilateral triangle."
    elif a == b and a != c and b != c:
        print "Isosceles triangle."
    elif (a==sqrt(b*b+c*c) or b==sqrt(a*a+c*c) or c==sqrt(a*a+b*b)):
        print "Right triangle."
    else:
        print "Simple triangle."
else:
    print "The shape is not a triangle."
```

When I insert "2", "2" and "2" everything is working well, but when i enter "3" , "4" and "5" I get:
"The shape is not a triangle." . Can you help me find the problem? (I saw now that I could find the solution on another post, but I ... didn't know the problem)

Comment: For one, you messed up Pythagoras' theorem:)

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string, not numbers. You need `int(raw_input("First length: "))` or `float(raw_input("First length: "))`. it works for the same inputs because you are comparing strings that are the same. Once the string representation of those numbers changes, none of the `elif` clauses are true

Comment: The `b != c` check is redundant; it is guaranteed to be true if the preceding two comparisons are true.

Comment: @chepner Oh, yes. I didn't realize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Python 2.7**:

`raw_input` returns a `str` value. Either use `input()` OR typecast the `raw_input()` to `int` as:

```
int(raw_input("First length: "))
```

**In Python 3**

There is only `input()` performing the same action as `raw_input()` of Python 2.x, and `raw_input` don't exist in Python 3

***Note***: As per the [Python 2.7 Document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

> `input('Something Something ...')` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input('Something Something ...'))`.

And we should not prefer using `eval` in the code due to security reasons. Read: [Is using eval in Python a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Don't recommend `input`. Python 3 got rid of it for a reason.

Comment: But user has mentioned tag as `python 2.7`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri true, and `input` exists. However, it calls `eval()` on the input in Python 2.7, and `eval` is not safe.

Comment: Right; if it was Python 3, you wouldn't have a choice. `input` simply should not be used; use `raw_input` in its place and convert the value to the type you want, instead of letting Python guess and perhaps do more than you intended.

Comment: I agree with both of you on that. Added the Note on why input should not be used